How can I change individual versions of services in akka.net cluster?
I am trying to build an Akka.Net clustered application. It forms a cluster and I can query with the pbm tool:
> pbm localhost:9110 cluster show

The response:Response from the pbm command
My question is, how do I change that version to my defined version?
I've tried searching for the solution everywhere. There doesn't seem to be a detailed documentation or guide. I am hoping to find the solution here.

The version number is determined by your executing assembly version by default, so you can just bump that like you would for any use case. However, if you want to set the version manually via HOCON you can do that via the akka.cluster.app-version setting.
Make sure you read about the constraints for acceptable version numbers here: https://getakka.net/articles/configuration/modules/akka.cluster.html
